# R: Skip labels in discrete x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, discrete

I am trying to produce something akin to a histogram of incomes with `ggplot2`. However, because I am not trying to show the frequency in the y-axis but a calculated variable from my data.frame, I figured I had to use `geom_bar()` and assign buckets as a new factor variable in my `data.frame`. Now I would like to show all bars I have determined a bucket for, but not show all labels on the x-axis. I figured there must be some way to do this with the `breaks =` in `scale_x_discrete()`, but couldn't figure out how to get this to just take "show me every second label" or something like that.

Would anyone have a suggestion for how to just show every second label on the x-axis for a discrete x-axis based upon a factor variable?

(Thank you very much for anyone's help and sorry, if I'm throwing around the wrong terms here. I'm new to R and just trying to describe everything as accurately as I can.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can provide function to the `breaks` argument that can handle special break rules. In the example below, we're choosing all odd breaks by recycling `c(TRUE, FALSE)` as a subset operation.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = function(x){x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]})
```

[image]

Some more explanation:

The logical index is repeated until it matches the length of the vector it indexes. If the logical index is `c(TRUE, FALSE)` if will keep repeating this, so it effectively picks up every odd element of the vector `x` because the length 2 index is repeated.

```r
x <- 1:9

x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
#> [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

So when you make a length 3 index, this will get repeated 3 times.

```r
x[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]
#> [1] 1 3 4 6 7 9
```

If you want to replicate what is going on under the hood, here is how you'd do it.

```r
i <- rep_len(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(x))

x[i]
#> [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect! That works! Could you just explain the logic behind this? I've just added more instances of `FALSE` after the one that you put in to get less elements shown on the x-axis.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain some more