# Specify scale_x_discrete for cut of continuous variabale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a continuous `time` variable and I want to plot a heatmap of values. To do so using `ggplot` and `geom_tile()` I bin the `time` into `time_bin` and parse the bounds of the resulting intervals. My question is somewhat related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395469/how-to-use-scale-x-discrete-with-intervals-created-by-cut), which has no answer.

Here's a toy `data.frame`

```
grouped_df [36 × 5] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ y       : chr [1:36] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ time_bin: Factor w/ 100 levels "(-0.03,0.3]",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ value   : num [1:36] -0.4 -0.512 -0.608 -0.725 0.757 ...
 $ low     : num [1:36] -0.03 0.3 0.601 0.901 -0.03 0.3 0.601 0.901 -0.03 0.3 ...
 $ high    : num [1:36] 0.3 0.601 0.901 1.2 0.3 0.601 0.901 1.2 0.3 0.601 ...
 - attr(*, "groups")= tibble [9 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ y    : chr [1:9] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ .rows: list<int> [1:9] 
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 5 6 7 8
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 9 10 11 12
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 13 14 15 16
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 17 18 19 20
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 21 22 23 24
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 25 26 27 28
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 29 30 31 32
  .. ..$ : int [1:4] 33 34 35 36
  .. ..@ ptype: int(0) 
  ..- attr(*, ".drop")= logi TRUE
> dput(toy)
structure(list(y = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", 
"9", "9"), time_bin = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("(-0.03,0.3]", 
"(0.3,0.601]", "(0.601,0.901]", "(0.901,1.2]", "(1.2,1.5]", "(1.5,1.8]", 
"(1.8,2.1]", "(2.1,2.4]", "(2.4,2.7]", "(2.7,3]", "(3,3.3]", 
"(3.3,3.6]", "(3.6,3.9]", "(3.9,4.2]", "(4.2,4.5]", "(4.5,4.81]", 
"(4.81,5.11]", "(5.11,5.41]", "(5.41,5.71]", "(5.71,6.01]", "(6.01,6.31]", 
"(6.31,6.61]", "(6.61,6.91]", "(6.91,7.21]", "(7.21,7.51]", "(7.51,7.81]", 
"(7.81,8.11]", "(8.11,8.41]", "(8.41,8.71]", "(8.71,9.01]", "(9.01,9.31]", 
"(9.31,9.61]", "(9.61,9.91]", "(9.91,10.2]", "(10.2,10.5]", "(10.5,10.8]", 
"(10.8,11.1]", "(11.1,11.4]", "(11.4,11.7]", "(11.7,12]", "(12,12.3]", 
"(12.3,12.6]", "(12.6,12.9]", "(12.9,13.2]", "(13.2,13.5]", "(13.5,13.8]", 
"(13.8,14.1]", "(14.1,14.4]", "(14.4,14.7]", "(14.7,15]", "(15,15.3]", 
"(15.3,15.6]", "(15.6,15.9]", "(15.9,16.2]", "(16.2,16.5]", "(16.5,16.8]", 
"(16.8,17.1]", "(17.1,17.4]", "(17.4,17.7]", "(17.7,18]", "(18,18.3]", 
"(18.3,18.6]", "(18.6,18.9]", "(18.9,19.2]", "(19.2,19.5]", "(19.5,19.8]", 
"(19.8,20.1]", "(20.1,20.4]", "(20.4,20.7]", "(20.7,21]", "(21,21.3]", 
"(21.3,21.6]", "(21.6,21.9]", "(21.9,22.2]", "(22.2,22.5]", "(22.5,22.8]", 
"(22.8,23.1]", "(23.1,23.4]", "(23.4,23.7]", "(23.7,24]", "(24,24.3]", 
"(24.3,24.6]", "(24.6,24.9]", "(24.9,25.2]", "(25.2,25.5]", "(25.5,25.8]", 
"(25.8,26.1]", "(26.1,26.4]", "(26.4,26.7]", "(26.7,27]", "(27,27.3]", 
"(27.3,27.6]", "(27.6,27.9]", "(27.9,28.2]", "(28.2,28.5]", "(28.5,28.8]", 
"(28.8,29.1]", "(29.1,29.4]", "(29.4,29.7]", "(29.7,30.1]"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(-0.400237814865178, -0.511748154576217, -0.608275784372335, 
    -0.7247244523613, 0.757330374272958, 0.776718248240655, 0.790724987842227, 
    0.998768292393676, 1.77979507741577, 1.52945992260953, 1.23688248753942, 
    0.908341101522855, -1.19238496743088, -1.26961869177189, 
    -1.32516082947541, -1.38508403291503, -0.629615898978496, 
    -0.620941659841269, -0.654461627603879, -0.751893145646679, 
    2.37041367819975, 2.51316431734167, 2.79123079147629, 3.1167959195256, 
    -0.519653805023003, -0.660372294607146, -0.972330338954077, 
    -1.31768889807071, 2.11290890332694, 2.21939390456188, 2.21971276073297, 
    2.15853062905871, 0.0602363209937846, 0.296034218681414, 
    0.372831656177899, 0.273945402834637), low = c(-0.03, 0.3, 
    0.601, 0.901, -0.03, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, -0.03, 0.3, 0.601, 
    0.901, -0.03, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, -0.03, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 
    -0.03, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, -0.03, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, -0.03, 
    0.3, 0.601, 0.901, -0.03, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901), high = c(0.3, 
    0.601, 0.901, 1.2, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 1.2, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 
    1.2, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 1.2, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 1.2, 0.3, 
    0.601, 0.901, 1.2, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 1.2, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 
    1.2, 0.3, 0.601, 0.901, 1.2)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), groups = structure(list(
    y = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:16, 17:20, 21:24, 25:28, 29:32, 33:36), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

To plot it, I use

```
toy %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x=time_bin, y=y, fill=value), color=NA)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = unique(time_bin[length(time_bin)/2])))
```

Which produces

[image]

I would like the x axis to be labeled only using the first portion of the breaks (-0.03, 0.3, ...). I have been trying to use `scale_x_discrete(breaks, labels)` with different approaches but haven't made much progress. The x scale is long in the real data, so ideally it I would be able to do something like `scale_x_discrete(breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(5))`, but that's also not working.

I also tried using the `low` and `high` values that I parse from the cut, but that creates tile plots that contain vertical white lines everywhere.

### Update

Using insight from one of the answers, I used `factor(low)` because my parsing works well, but the proposed `readr::parse_number()` does not. This gets the labels into the proper format.

The remaining portion of the question would be, how to show less factor levels using `scale_x_discrete(breaks = ...)` ?

For example, this seems to decimate the axis, a bit cumbersome but kinda works (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275692/r-skip-labels-in-discrete-x-axis))

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks = function(x){x[c(rep(FALSE, 9), TRUE)]})+
```

### EDIT

For completeness....I am parsing the results from `cut` using

```
parse_cuts <- function(x){
  # This f(x) is made to be used as
  # mutate(map_df(time_bin, function(.x) parse_cuts(as.character(.x))))
  out <- sapply(strsplit(x, "\\(|,|]"), function(qq) as.numeric(qq[-1]))[,1]
  names(out) <- c("low", "high")
  return(unlist(out))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `parse_number` from `readr` package it is in `tidyverse`. To apply here we first have to transform `time_bin` to character:

Update: transformed x to factor(x)

```
library(tidyverse)
toy %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(parse_number(as.character(time_bin)))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value), color=NA)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = unique(x[length(x)/2])))
  xlab("time_bin")
```

[image]

Comment: This I like this, but in my actual example, the `vline` doesn't show and I think the call to `factor` is messing up my level ordering in my real data. It might be a failure to parse? For example, the bin `(21,21.3]` gets parsed as `2121.3000`

Comment: Please see my edits about `scale_x_discrete()`

Comment: just add factor to x like : ` mutate(x = factor(parse_number(as.character(time_bin))))`. See my update:

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to solve this, using insight from other answers. Not the prettiest but somewhat gets the job done. It might be a good idea to do a labeller function, like `label_decimate()` to produce the subset.

```
toy %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(low)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value), color=NA)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = unique(x[length(x)/2])))+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = function(x){x[c(rep(FALSE, 9), TRUE)]})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple base-r solution is to `gsub` the left edge of the interval out and `cbind` this to the `data` argument of `ggplot`. A slightly different regex (`^.*,([-.0-9]+).$`) would allow you to extract the right edge.

```
ggplot(cbind(toy, "time" = gsub("^.([-.0-9]+),.*$", "\\1", toy$time_bin))) +
    geom_tile(aes(x=time, y=y, fill=value), color=NA)+
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = unique(time[length(time)/2])))
```

[image]

However, **this is misleading**, as the x axis "looks" continuous, but is in fact a series of stacked factors which just happen to be in order and roughly contiguous. A better approach is to turn the x `aes` into a genuine numeric, which will also let you specify your `scale` breaks more easily.

```
ggplot(cbind(toy, "time" = as.numeric(gsub("^.([-.0-9]+),.*$", "\\1", toy$time_bin)))) +
 geom_tile(aes(x=time, y=y, fill=value), color=NA)+
 geom_vline(aes(xintercept = unique(time[length(time)/2])))
```

[image]

Note however that this will leave gaps where the tile sizes don't quite match (the distance between -0.030 and 0.300 is bigger than that between 0.300 and 0.601, and this is correctly shown here). If this is true in your real data, you can either fudge the width of the `geom_tile`, or use `geom_rect` and specify `xmax` and `xmin` from the left and right edges of the cut interval.

```
ggplot(cbind(toy, 
             "time_l" = as.numeric(gsub("^.([-.0-9]+),.*$", "\\1", toy$time_bin)),
             "time_r" = as.numeric(gsub("^.*,([-.0-9]+).$", "\\1", toy$time_bin)),
             "y_l" = as.numeric(toy$y) - 0.5, 
             "y_r" = as.numeric(toy$y) + 0.5
             )) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=time_l, xmax=time_r, ymin=y_l, ymax=y_r, fill=value), color=NA)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = unique(time_l[length(time_l)/2])))
```

[image]